# X ~ N(0,1) What is the CDF of random vector $ \begin{pmatrix} X\\ X\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: probability-theory

Is this the degenerate case? Would the CDF just be that of the standard normal?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$,
$$
\Pr(X\leq x_1,X\leq x_2)=\Pr(X\leq\min\{x_1,x_2\})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\min\{x_1,x_2\}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx.
$$

Answer (score 3):

I had done the same calculation as @yurnero. As a complement to the solution he has given, here is a graphical representation, too rarely done for a 2 dimensional cdf. I have used Mathematica with the following instruction:

Plot3D[0.5*Erf[Min[x, y]] + 0.5, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},

PlotPoints -> 200, Mesh -> False, ViewPoint -> {-5, -3, 5}]

(Erf is the error function)

[image]